# append variable from multiple function which call ajax requests

Tags: ajax, function, loops

I am having trouble setting a markup variable with multiple ajax requests call by functions.  The number of function will not be know, but for this example I made 2 and put them in the same js file.  I am trying to loop though an unknown number of functions and append a markup variable with the response.

However the ajax request isn't finished before the function ends.  How can I make sure I get a response back from ajax before proceeding?

getMarkup() will run on document.ready

```
function getMarkup(){
    var news = [];
    news.push('loadnews1');
    news.push('loadnews2');
    len = news.length;
    var markup;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        try{
           markup = eval(news[i] + '();');
        }catch(ex){

       }
    }
    console.log(markup);
}

function loadnews1(){

    var host = 'http://test.com';
    var path = '/ajax-feeds/news/json1';
    var markup = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: host + path,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                markup += '<div id="new-row-'+key+'" class="news-row">' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-image"><img src="'+value.picture+'"></div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-title">'+value.title+'</div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-title">'+value.subtitle+'</div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-teaser">'+value.body+'</div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-link"><a href="http://test.com/'+value.nid+'">More Link</a></div></div>';
            });
            return markup;
        }
    });

}

function loadnews2(){

    var host = 'http://test.com';
    var path = '/ajax-feeds/news/json2';
    var markup = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: host + path,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                markup += '<div id="new-row-'+key+'" class="news-row">' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-image"><img src="'+value.picture+'"></div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-title">'+value.title+'</div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-title">'+value.subtitle+'</div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-teaser">'+value.body+'</div>' +
                 '<div class="news-row-spotlight-link"><a href="http://test.com/'+value.nid+'">More Link</a></div></div>';
            });
            return markup;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Ajax functions are Asynchronous (the "A" in Ajax), you will need a callback function to ensure it has completed.

Comment: You can declare variable `var markup` global means instead of in all the function declare it on top. It should give you desired output but it can effect also as if `loadNews2()` returns response earlier then `markup` changes.

Comment: @tymeJV well the fun on AJAX is that it must not be asyncronous nor must it be combined with XML. You could make a syncrounus "json" call with it :-)